# How to install PHP SSH2 extension in a non-standard folder on linux without root access

Tags: php, linux

I am way out of my area of expertise and have scoured the internet and stackoverflow for a solution to this problem with none to be found. I am trying to install the PHP SSH2 extension in my account's folder on a linux (don't know which flavor) shared hosting server where I don't have root access.

I was able to successfully create libssh2-1.4.3 in a private folder with the following commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/myaccnt/php/ssh2/install
make
make install
```

and end up with the following files in the `/home/myaccnt/php/ssh2/install/lib` folder:

```
libssh2.a
libssh2.la
libssh2.so
libssh2.so.1
libssh2.so.1.0.1
```

So far, so good (at least I think so good).

Next, I tried to build ssh2-0.11.3 but I can't get past the configure step. I have tried several different ways to run the configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/myaccnt/php/ssh2/install --with-ssh2=/home/myaccnt/php/ssh2/install
./configure --prefix=/home/myaccnt/php/ssh2/install --with-ssh2=/home/myaccnt/php/ssh2/install/lib
```

but the configure script always can't find libssh2 and I get the following messages:

```
checking for ssh2 support... yes, shared
checking for ssh2 files in default path... not found
configure: error: The required libssh2 library was not found.  You can obtain that package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libssh2/
```

So, the question is, how do I get the PHP SSH2 extension configure script to find libssh2?

Thanks in advance for you help. It really is appreciated.

Comment: This might be better fitted for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I doubt you can do this, unless you can install it in Apache just for your usage. Are you able to run a per-user php.ini, do you know? That might give you a glimmer of hope, but tbh it might just be easier to switch to a VPS.

Comment: account specific php.ini is premitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours poking through the configure script and even more hours searching the internet, I figured out a way to accomplish this. For those that might be interested in doing something similar, here's what I did.

I started with instructions at [www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php) and did the following:

Create libssh2:

1. Created a folder under my home directory called "php" and then a folder within it called "ext" and another folder called "ssh2".
2. `cd /<myhome>/php/ssh2`
3. download the libssh2 package from [libssh2.org](http://libssh2.org) into the php/ssh2 folder
4. `tar vxzf libssh2-1.4.3.tar.gz`
5. `cd libssh2-1.4.3`
6. `./configure --prefix=$HOME`
7. `make`
8. `make install`

Create ssh2:

1. `cd /<myhome>/php/ssh2`
2. download the php-ssh2 package from [pecl.php.net/package/ssh2](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)
3. `tar vxzf ssh2-0.11.3`
4. `cd ssh2-0.11.3`
5. `phpize`
6. `./configure --prefix=$HOME --with-ssh2=$HOME`
7. `make`

Copied `/<myhome>/ssh2-0.11.3/modules/ssh2.so` to `/<myhome>/php/ext/ssh2.so`

Modified my php.ini to include `extension=/<myhome>/php/ext/ssh2.so`

And now I have ssh2 available to my scripts on a shared server. Hope someone find this helpful.